# IE9 platform preview debug tool: How do I show file and line numbers for exceptions/errors

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to get [noVNC](https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC) working with Internet Explorer 9 (platform preview 7). The developer tools window (F12) is greatly improved over previous version of IE. However, the tools don't report script file name or line number when exceptions are thrown.

Is there a straight forward way to match exceptions messages in the developer tools to the location in the Javascript where it occurred? (Other than brute force search by adding console messages to the code).

**Update:**

I discovered that the code causing the exception is within a try/catch block. If I don't catch the exception the behavior is worse: I never seen anything reported at all. But I can tell it has stopped executing based on console.log debug messages before and after (the ones after never fire). So I guess the question still remains, how do I get IE9 dev tools to show the location where console message (especially console.error) came from in the script the same way that Chrome dev tools and firefox firebug?

Answer (score 0):

Which PPB version are you using?

Did you click the "Start Debugging" button on the SCRIPT tab in the F12 tools? If so, it *should* be breaking into your code at the exact point of the exception.

Comment: PP7 (from Nov 17th). I've done "Start Debugging" and then reloaded the page. It didn't change the behavior. The exception happens about 2 seconds after page load. The execution stops at the exception (whether with debug or not) but the script is not loaded in the window and there is no other way I see to correlate line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by selecting and adding a break-point to an arbitrary entry point in the JavaScript and using step into indiscriminately.